# Nagios doesn't send notifications in specific time

Tags: nagios

I have a problem with Nagios.

Here's my service definition:

```
define service{
    use                             generic-service
    host_name                       Server1
    service_description             Check My Own Sfutt
    check_command                   check_nrpe!check_mystuff
    contact_groups                  IT
    notification_interval           60
    check_interval                  60
    check_period                    from12to04
    }
```

My timeperiod:

```
# FROM 12 AM TO 4 AM
define timeperiod{
    timeperiod_name from12to04
    alias           FROM 12 AM to 4 AM
    sunday          12:00-04:00
    monday          12:00-04:00
    tuesday         12:00-04:00
    wednesday       12:00-04:00
    thursday        10:00-04:00
    friday          12:00-04:00
    saturday        12:00-04:00
    }
```

But I don't get notification if the service is CRITICAL, then I check the service in Nagios and see the following:

```
Next Scheduled Check:   N/A
```

If I force run manually, it shows the critical state, but don't send a mail either. Then the nexs schedulded check time is N/A again. Any idea?

It works well If I don't use the notification_interval, the check_interval and the check_period options.

Comment: what version of Nagios is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First for the time period I think you want:# FROM 12 AM TO 4 AM

```
define timeperiod{
timeperiod_name from_noon_to4am
   alias           FROM 12 AM to 4 AM
   sunday          12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
   monday          12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
   tuesday         12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
   wednesday       12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
   thursday        12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
   friday          12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
   saturday        12:00-24:00,00:00-04:00
}
```

Second what are your settings for notifications? What does your state retention file show for this check?

```
 state_retention_file=/var/cache/icinga/retention.dat
```

Are you getting any email from Nagios?

Comment: Hey,

That caused the problem. I want to check 12:00-04:00, so from noon to other day 04 am. Any idea?

Comment: Will update the config above